# Maven Eclipse: How to include custom folder (with files) into the "target" folder on build?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I have an Eclipse-Maven project. In that project I have created a custom foldr called `installScripts` and has 3 files.
I want this folder (with its content) to be present in my `target` folder when I build the pom.xml file.
Below is my folder structure:

[image]

My POM.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.comcast.mongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongoRead</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7</version>
            <!--<scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/ojdbc-7.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
            <artifactId>java.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: try maven resources plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

Move Installed Scripts directory to Resources and try. i.e under src/main/resources

Comment: if required use a subfolder in this src/main/resources folder like src/main/resources/installScripts